# Paypal payment failure

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

for getting IPN post to my website i have changed some settings in my sandbox account.
After when i;m trying to buy in paypal side this error occured each time 
Rapids::Exception (N6Rapids5Tools13PimpExceptionE): Pimp RC: 3514

```
Failure log: Use of pimp_rc (3013), Use of pimp_rc (14816), Use of pimp_rc (9449), Use of pimp_rc (9445), Use of pimp_rc (3198), Use of pimp_rc (3011), Use of pimp_rc (10021), Use of pimp_rc (3199), Use of pimp_rc (3015), Use of pimp_rc (3014), Use of pimp_rc (3200), Use of pimp_rc (3257), Use of pimp_rc (3012), Use of pimp_rc (3141), Use of pimp_rc (3535), Use of pimp_rc (3504), Use of pimp_rc (10022), Use of pimp_rc (6702), Use of pimp_rc (3001), Use of pimp_rc (3120), Use of pimp_rc (3517), Use of pimp_rc (3531), Use of pimp_rc (3201), Use of pimp_rc (3803), Use of pimp_rc (6834), Use of pimp_rc (3807), Use of pimp_rc (3808), Use of pimp_rc (3810), Use of pimp_rc (3812), Use of pimp_rc (3809), Use of pimp_rc (3805), Use of pimp_rc (2002), Use of pimp_rc (3177), Use of pimp_rc (3051), Use of pimp_rc (3510), Use of pimp_rc (4003), Use of pimp_rc (3013), Use of pimp_rc (4011), Use of pimp_rc (3300), Use of pimp_rc (3286), Use of pimp_rc (6681), Use of pimp_rc (14605), Use of pimp_rc (10361), Use of pimp_rc (14353), Use of pimp_rc (14817), Use of pimp_rc (4002), Use of pimp_rc (2001), Use of pimp_rc (4001), Use of pimp_rc (11045), Use of pimp_rc (3593), Use of pimp_rc (4071), Use of pimp_rc (3514), Use of pimp_rc (4022), Use of pimp_rc (4003), Use of pimp_rc (4003), Use of pimp_rc (4003), Use of pimp_rc (4011), Use of pimp_rc (4011), (rcf @ virtual int Merchant::PimpAutoSellerBLIImpl::seller_generate_transaction_token(ullong, PimpTransID&):406) , Use of pimp_rc (3514) Backtrace: Rapids::Tools::PimpException::PimpException() Rapids::BusinessBlocks::HostedPayments::get_synch_ipn_url(PayPalCommonWebAppContext const&, unsigned long long, String const&, String const&, String&, PimpTransaction const&, MiscUbiquityContainer&, TransactionUbiquityContainer&, String const&, unsigned long long) Rapids::BusinessBlocks::HostedPayments::get_synch_ipn_url(PayPalCommonWebAppContext const&, PimpXClick&, PimpTransaction const&, MiscUbiquityContainer&, TransactionUbiquityContainer&, unsigned long long) Rapids::Flows::HostedPayments::StateAutoreturnCheck::execute(Rapids::CGIVars const&) Rapids::DecoratedState::execute(Rapids::CGIVars const&) Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::handle_execute(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate const&, Rapids::TransitionRegistry const&, Rapids::State*, String const&, String const&, unsigned long long) Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::process_states(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate const&, Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::ProcessStates, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&, Rapids::TransitionEdge const*) Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::flow_continue_from_interception(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::call_rapids(Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::RapidsFlowFactory const&, Riprap::DispatchAction const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, String const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::dispatch_loop(Riprap::EPRegistry const&, Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::DispatchAction&, Riprap::WebAppReturn&, String const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::dispatch_wrapper(OutputStream&, Riprap::EPRegistry const&, Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, String const&, bool const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::entry_point(HTTPInterface&, Riprap::CGIVars&, OutputStream&, String const&, String const&) main

An error has occurred.
```

why , i have set all settings right as it described in http://help.wildapricot.com/display/DOC/PayPal+account+setup
but pasting  PDT token, because i couldn't find the place to past it

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this before and it's the most unhelpful error message in the world. However, it is related to either the merchant account or the buyer account not being verified. Log in to each one separately at http://sandbox.paypal.com/ and click the Verify account. Just follow the steps, it doesn't require any real life information.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this in case anybody else runs into this problem. Both my seller and buyer sandbox accounts were verified and I still got this error.

For me this error was fixed when I did my testing in an Incognito window. I did 10+ test payments without error while before it would always show these errors after 2 or 3 payments.

I assume that this is a sandbox only error, because I have never seen this error on a live account (and probably did close to a hundred payments in the past using a live account).

Answer (score 2):

I got this ridiculous error message when using a fake email address (test@test.com).

Once I used my real email address, which has an account on the real PayPal website, the error disappeared.

After that, doing the following made a new Sandbox account:

- Use a real PayPal account email (for the purchaser)
- Login with your password - it says "username/password not found"
- Do it again
- On the third time, there is a Guest User button.

  Click it, enter card details and make the payment.
- After payment, it asks if you want to create a new account - say yes.

Now the customer account exists on the Sandbox website, and you can login for the next test.