# my sandbox paypal error when make a purchase

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox

[image]

please help, I'm getting this error when I want to test purchase.how do I resolve this error? I have read a few thing about this , the option said that I have to verify my email address but I already check in my developer account, there is no way to verify this test account.Help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517568/paypal-payment-failure

Comment: okay thanks for help